# Reopen the PHP on iPad question

Tags: support, vote-to-reopen

I think we should re-open [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/97363/php-programming-in-ipad/97368#97368) on how to get a PHP stack on iPad as it seems it's [technically possible](http://www.ipadforums.net/ipad-hacking/24007-running-php-server-ipad.html) to get a minimal but working lighttp / PHP stack after all.

Granted, the iPad is not the best device to code on, but if it's technically possible the question is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While that's interesting (albeit wildly not supported), it wasn't closed because there wasn't an answer: it was closed because setting up a LAMP environment isn't on-topic here.

To be honest, it's a pretty exotic and obscure problem: I'm not sure it'd survive on any site.

- A general question about setting up a LAMP environment would be on-topic for Super User, but they don't deal with iOS devices.
- A question about iOS devices would be on-topic for Apple, but they don't do development questions.
- Stack Overflow would be a fit if it's about general setting up of the development environment, but questions about getting Apache to run on non-conventional development machines would be off-topic and too localized.

Comment: I'm ok with the off-topic reasoning and I also agree that migrating a 3 months old question would be pointless. Your comment on the question (_it looks like you're a bit confused about what the iPad is actually capable of_) it's kind of suggesting that the questions was closed because of the impossibility of a PHP stack on the iPad. Which would be called iAMP btw, L is for Linux :)

Comment: @YannisRizos I can see that: I revised my comment to make it clear it was closed for the LAMP setup, not because it's an iPad. I also checked with other mods, and the general consensus seems to be there isn't a site where it'd be on-topic due to the exotic nature of the problem.

Comment: _figuring out how to get Apache running on an obscure device is off-topic_: Did you just call the iPad an obscure device? :)

Comment: @YannisRizos I think you know what I mean: obscure in the sense that there are probably only a handful of people who would ever seriously take the effort to run their LAMP dev stack off of an iPad. :)

Comment: I'm trying it right now... As useless as it might be, it'll be an instant hit on our next LUG meeting.

Comment: How would it be off-topic or too localized on Stack Overflow? It's on-topic as it related to development tools and development environments. Too localized is a toss-up, and for the Stack Overflow community to decide. I think it's relevant since it's asked in a way that's general enough to help anyone who wants to use their iPad for PHP development. Now, if that's a good idea to do is an entirely different discussion that has no bearing on if the question is a clear, well-asked, useful question, which I think it is.

Comment: @ThomasOwens I had checked with both the Stack Overflow moderators and people at Stack Exchange, Inc. last night: they had said this was something that would not have life on Stack Overflow due to the obscure nature of the problem. General questions about setting up a LAMP dev environment are on-topic there as long as they don't delve into troubleshooting issues like "My Apache server won't start, help!"

Comment: That's a little disappointing, but if they all say no, then I guess they don't want it. I don't own an iPad (or any iDevice), but I thought it was an interesting question that deserves a good home, especially since I know a bunch of people who own iDevices and are like "hey, look what I did to it this weekend!" with crazy random things like putting PHP on it.